# Can't locate textbox elements from login page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Image below is our example login page. I'm having issue locating the username and password elements.

This is the tag.

```
<input id="userId" class="Textbox required" type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="_ssoUser"/>
```

[Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtHsb.jpg)

Below are the codes that I've tried but still no luck to solve it.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("_ssoUser")).sendKeys(username);

driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys(username);

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userId']")).sendKeys(username);
```

Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: do you get `NoSuchElement` exception or `ElementNotVisible`?

Comment: i didnt tried using placeholder but oneof my colleague told me that it is impossible to do operation using placeholder as element

Comment: Is it inside `ifram`?

Comment: I'm getting Unable to locate element.

Comment: is this dynamically loaded? Try to wait some time after the page load and before trying to access the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wait by using implicit wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

After that see if there is a frame or not

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

You can handle frame by many ways. refer below:-

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-iframes-in-selenium-webdriver

Note:- switch to frame first and then execute your rest of code.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: There is no frame available.

Answer (score 0):

look if you have frame if yes switch to it.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("<frameid> or <frame name>");
```

Comment: There is no frame available